# Fetch Nested JSON data in Go

Tags: json, go, struct

I keep running into the same problem, which is fetching data from nested JSON.

The struct looks like this, and my attempt at the solution is below.

The error I receive is "response.Result.Bid undefined" I have decoded the JSON response, so I do not quite understand what is going on here. The error occurs when I try to append to the array.

I'll appreciate any help, and if you guys have any good resources related to this topic that I can read about lmk because I keep running into the same problem. I do not come from a programming background, I am a mathematician by trade.

```
type MarketPrices struct {
    Success bool `json:"success"`
    Result  []struct {
        Name           string      `json:"name"`
        Basecurrency   interface{} `json:"baseCurrency"`
        Quotecurrency  interface{} `json:"quoteCurrency"`
        Type           string      `json:"type"`
        Underlying     string      `json:"underlying"`
        Enabled        bool        `json:"enabled"`
        Ask            float64     `json:"ask"`
        Bid            float64     `json:"bid"`
        Last           float64     `json:"last"`
        Postonly       bool        `json:"postOnly"`
        Priceincrement float64     `json:"priceIncrement"`
        Sizeincrement  float64     `json:"sizeIncrement"`
        Restricted     bool        `json:"restricted"`
    } `json:"result"`
}
```

```
func Spot_Price() []float64 {
    res, err := http.Get("https://ftx.com/api/markets/BTC/USD")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var arr []float64

    var response MarketPrices
    json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&response)

    arr = append(arr, response.Result.Bid)

    arr = append(arr, response.Result.Ask)

    return arr
}
```

Comment: `Result` is an array: `response.Result[0].Bid` would give you the first result's Bid, you can `for _,result:=range response.Result {...}` to scan all results.

Answer (score 1):

With the actual response in question [1], no slice is returned. This would be a
better modeling of the response:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
   "net/http"
)

type MarketPrices struct {
   Success bool
   Result struct {
      Ask, Bid, Last, Priceincrement, Sizeincrement  float64
      Basecurrency, Name, Quotecurrency, Type, Underlying     string
      Enabled, Postonly, Restricted     bool
   }
}

func request() (*MarketPrices, error) {
   res, err := http.Get("https://ftx.com/api/markets/BTC/USD")
   if err != nil { return nil, err }
   defer res.Body.Close()
   response := new(MarketPrices)
   json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(response)
   return response, nil
}

func main() {
   price, err := request()
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", price)
}
```

1. https://ftx.com/api/markets/BTC/USD